# Keep first column visible in datagridview when scrolling sideways

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, floating

I'd need a way to keep the first column visible in a `Datagridview` when i scroll sideways, like you can do in Excel. To sort of "float" on top of the other cells and remain allways visible. I've searched around quite a lot but wasnt able to find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [freeze the datagridview column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").Frozen = True
```

Comment: yay! thank you very much! can accept your answer only in 10 minutes!